# How to open multiple connections using popen in python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am trying to copy a file from file system "A" to file system "B". So I need connections to both A and B at the same time using 2 different username/passwords.
My current implementation is like the following:

```
def main():
    CMD_src = 'NET USE ' + network_scr + ' /User:' + user_src + ' ' + password_src
    CMD_dst = 'NET USE ' + network_dst + ' /User:' + user_dst + ' ' + password_dst
    conn_src = subprocess.Popen(CMD_src, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    conn_dst = subprocess.Popen(CMD_dst, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    copy()
    conn_src.kill()
    conn_dst.kill()
```

This will give me an error "Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again."

Can anyone help me in this case? Thank you very much!!

Comment: This seems like it has nothing to do with Python, and everything to do with your system refusing to do what you're asking it to: you ask it to please connect to some server(s) as two different users at the same time, and it says "you can't do that".  You'll have to find a way to achieve the goal while only connecting as one user at a time, e.g., get file as user A and keep it somewhere local, disconnect as user A, connect as user B, copy file to remote, discard local copy.

Answer (score 0):

You might try connecting to the two different servers in two different threads. http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html